# Is there an alternative insert to the built in wide panel for the Canon 430 EX ii speedlite?

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash

I recently purchased the 430 ex II speedlite second hand. I have come to notice that the wide panel is missing and as such I cannot alter the zoom on the speedlite unless there is something maintaining compression on the little button at the base of where the wide panel would normally be. Is anyone aware of alternative fixes without the need to to replace the wide panel?

Comment: Given that you can pick up [a new wide-panel assembly for around $20](https://uscamera.com/product/canon-speedlite-430ex-ii-wide-panel-assembly-cy2-4265/), is there a specific reason you want to do this without a replacement?

Comment: Time limitation

Comment: Old credit card, cut to size, held in with clear tape, as a stop-gap? [re: answers in comments, will move to answer if it works]